# Find line's sum if start with numeric value in a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file containing data that is,

```
a b c d e
1 2 3 4 5
f g h i j
6 7 8 9 10
k l m n o
11 12 13 14 15
```

and required output is 0, 15, 0, 40, 0, 65.
My attempt

```
f=open("C:/Users/kaleemi/Desktop/text.txt","r+")
s=0  
for line in f:  
    for i in line:  
        if i.isnumeric():  
            s=s+int(i)  
        else:  
            continue  
    print(s)  
    s=0
```

output:0, 15, 0, 31, 0, 20.

Please help me to correct this code.

Comment: I think you're adding digits and not numbers, so for 6 7 8 9 10 you're doing 6+7+8+9+1+0

Comment: You need to split the line on "space" rather than getting a single digit

Comment: oneliner version: `>>> input = ['a b c d e', '1 2 3 4 5', 'f g h i j', '6 7 8 9 10', 'k l m n o', '11 12 13 14 15']
>>> [sum([int(i) for i in j.split() if i.isnumeric()]) for j in input]
[0, 15, 0, 40, 0, 65]`

Comment: Please clarify: what would you do with input lines of `1 a 2 b` (starts with a number) and `a 1 b 2` (starts with non-number, but contains numbers)?

Comment: only start with a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you added up the *digits* in each line, instead of the numbers.  `split` the line in individual numbers and change *those* to `int`.

```
s=0  
for line in f:  
    for i in line.split():  
        if i.isnumeric():  
            s=s+int(i)  
    print(s)  
    s=0
```

Output:

```
0
15
0
40
0
65
```

Note that I removed the useless `continue`.

If you need the output in a single line, you'll need to collect them in a list and print them after you've read all the input lines.  I retained the format of your original program.

Yes, this *can* be done with `sum` on a list comprehension with a filter.  I'm also keeping to your current programming level.

Comment: What happens if a line was `1 2 a b c`? I think your code would return 3 instead of 0 however that may also not be a requirement.

Comment: @DanielGale: the original code would also return `3`.

Comment: Thank you sir Prune

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy

with open("/Users/michael/Desktop/text.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    try:
        l = list(map(float, line.rstrip().split(" ")))
        mean = int(numpy.sum(l))
    except ValueError:
        mean = 0
    print(mean)
```

Comment: This appears to miss the crux of OP's problem: you blithely assume that the data have already been read as properly formatted fields.

Comment: The first line isn't ` ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`, it's `a b c d e`. The second line isn't `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, it's `1 2 3 4 5`. Your code will return 0 for all lines, because all lines contain spaces. The central issue the OP is having is in parsing strings as numbers, and your "simulation" has the strings already parsed as numbers.